# Disable Running React Project In Incognito Visual Studio 2022

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I've a standalone React project. I'm using VisualStudio 2022 Preview 2 as the IDE. Every time I launches the react webapp by clicking on green play icon in VS, It launches an Incognito Chrome window.

Is there any way I can launch the application in normal Chrome window?

This is the launch.json file inside `.vscode` folder

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "localhost (Chrome)",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "localhost (Edge)",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve this? I figured there might be some kind of settings when selecting the the browser to start with. The start icon (green arrow triangle) has a drop down where you can select settings and the browsers.